Unable to find this components 1.ColorPicker & 2.List with Drag and Drop functionality in Apache Royale
Unable to find ColorPicker in Apache Royale and I found this component colorpicker form mx controls https://royale.apache.org/asdoc/index.html#!mx.controls/ColorPicker but this mx controls are not working and facing compilition error like below, Suggest any alternate for colorpicker and List component with Drag and Drop functionality.

This is my code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->

<j:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:j="library://ns.apache.org/royale/jewel"
xmlns:js="library://ns.apache.org/royale/basic" xmlns:mx="library://ns.apache.org/royale/mx">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
                private function changeHandler(event:Event):void {
                    trace('CheckBox value is: ' + event.target.value, ' and selected state is: ' + event.target.selected);
                }
            ]]>
</fx:Script>

<j:beads>
    <js:ApplicationDataBinding />
</j:beads>

<j:initialView>
    <j:View>
        <j:beads>
            <js:Paddings padding="30" />
            <j:VerticalLayout gap="3" />
        </j:beads>

        <j:Label text="Binding the text property of a Jewel TextInput to update a text Label" />

        <j:VContainer width="100%" height="300" gap="3" itemsVerticalAlign="itemsBottom">
            <j:Card width="50%" height="100">
                <j:Label text="vert bottom" />
            </j:Card>
            <j:Card width="50%" height="100">
                <j:Label text="vert bottom" />
            </j:Card>
        </j:VContainer>

        <j:Container width="200" height="200" className="wrapper">
            <j:Button text="Origin" />
            <j:Button text="x:30,y:30" x="30" y="30" />
            <j:Button text="x:60,y:60" x="60" y="60" />
            <j:Button text="bottom/right" style="bottom:0;right:0" />
        </j:Container>

        <j:Group width="200" height="200" className="wrapper">
            <j:Button text="Origin" />
            <j:Button text="x:30,y:30" x="30" y="30" />
            <j:Button text="x:60,y:60" x="60" y="60" />
            <j:Button text="bottom/right" style="bottom:0;right:0" />
        </j:Group>


        <j:HGroup width="100%" height="300" gap="3" itemsHorizontalAlign="itemsCenter">
            <j:Card width="100" height="50%">
                <j:Label text="horz center" />
            </j:Card>
            <j:Card width="100" height="50%">
                <j:Label text="horz center" />
            </j:Card>
        </j:HGroup>


        <j:VContainer width="100%" height="300" gap="3" itemsVerticalAlign="itemsBottom">
            <j:Card width="50%" height="100">
                <j:Label text="vert bottom" />
            </j:Card>
            <j:Card width="50%" height="100">
                <j:Label text="vert bottom" />
            </j:Card>
        </j:VContainer>


        <j:HContainer width="100%" height="300" gap="3" itemsHorizontalAlign="itemsCenter">
            <j:Card width="100" height="50%">
                <j:Label text="horz center" />
            </j:Card>
            <j:Card width="100" height="50%">
                <j:Label text="horz center" />
            </j:Card>
            <j:CheckBox text="A Checkbox" value="50" change="changeHandler(event)" />
        </j:HContainer>

       
        <mx:ColorPicker id="environmentColorPicker" />

    </j:View>
</j:initialView>

</j:Application>

